# Integrate $\int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$
I=\int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}=?
$$
Thank you.  I don't know how to do it because the bounds on the integral, I feel like that is confusing me a lot more than it means to be.  I tried doing $x=\tan \theta$ but didn't work.

What I got was
$$
I=\int_1^\infty \frac{\sec^2\theta d\theta}{\tan \theta \sec\theta}=\int_1^\infty \frac{\sec \theta}{\tan \theta}d\theta=\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{\sin \theta}d\theta 
$$
but now I am stuck.  This can't be the the right way, also this integral Diverges...So I am not sure.

Also $x=\sin\theta,\cos \theta$ didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done by a change of variables which simplifies the integrand 
\begin{eqnarray}
y=\sqrt{x^2-1}\\  y^2=x^2-1, \ x=\sqrt{1+y^2}\\ ydy=xdx\\  y(1)=0,\ y(\infty)=\infty.
\end{eqnarray}

We can now write 
$$
I=\int_0^\infty \frac{dy}{1+y^2}=\tan^{-1} y\big|^\infty_0=\frac{\pi}{2}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

I see 2 problems.  The first is you didn't change the limits of integration to terms of $\theta$.  The second is you have your trig identity wrong.

$$\sec^2\theta-1=\tan^2\theta$$

Therefore, your substitution should be

$$x=\sec\theta,dx=\sec\theta\tan\theta d\theta$$

$$\theta=\cos^{-1}\frac1x$$

Now when we substitute we get

$$\int_0^\frac\pi2\frac{\sec\theta\tan\theta d\theta}{\sec\theta\tan\theta}$$

From here, the solution should be trivial.

Comment: Okay I see now mike thank you

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}\ dx=\sec^{-1}x|_1^\infty=\frac{\pi}{2}-0$$